# After Using Custom Sound in flutter Local notification package the app doesn't show notifications in terminated mode

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification, flutter-notification

I use flutter local notification package to show FCM notifications and every thing is okay it show notifications in foreground , background and terminated modes .
After I add custom sound Notification worked in foreground and background modes only .
Doesn't receive any thing in terminated mode .
When I open the app again I received the missed notifications "while terminated " .

Here is my notification class

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

 

class Noti{
  
  static AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    const   AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'SchoolGObus_horn',
      'SchoolGObus_horn',
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('bus_horn'),
      playSound: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
  static Future initialize(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    
    var  androidInitialize = const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
    var iOSInitialize =  const   DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationsSettings =   InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize,
        iOS: iOSInitialize);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  ?.createNotificationChannel(androidPlatformChannelSpecifics as AndroidNotificationChannel);
   

  }
 
  static Future showBigTextNotification({required String title, required String body,
    var payload, required FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin fln
  } ) async {
    int id = getRandomInteger() ;
    var not= NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: const  DarwinNotificationDetails()
    );
    await fln.show(id, title, body,not );
  }
  static int getRandomInteger() {
  final random = Random();
  return random.nextInt(10000);
}
}
```

Here is my Background Listen function :

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  Noti.initialize(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  Noti.showBigTextNotification(
      title: '${message.data['action']}',
      body: '${message.data['message']}',
      fln: flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
}
```

Here is related code in main :

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  AppConstance.deviceToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  Noti.initialize(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

And I have flutter local notification  as global

```
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
```

I need notification working in terminated mode